# What does たいがい mean here?

Tags: translation

Another rock star tweet that I don't understand. Here the word たいがい confuses me.

いや、しん様には負けます( ；´Д｀)RT @shinji_sid: いやいやあなたもたいがい…RT @mao_sid: しん様(((o(*ﾟ▽ﾟ*)o)))今日もイケメンでした(((o(*ﾟ▽ﾟ*)o)))RT @shinji_sid: ♪(´ε｀ )つティモテ

It looks like they are complimenting each other on how beautiful they are.

What does it say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`大概` (taigai) in this context means 'to a decent degree'. In the example, they are being modest to each other. A person is praised for something, and that person says that that appies to the other person as well to a decent degree. Depending on the context, it may be an irony, and they may actually be blaming each other.

To my understanding, this is used in the Kansai dialects. Another usage is as follows. They both mean the same.

> - 大概にせいよ [Kansai dialect]
> - いい加減にしろ [Tokyo dialect]
> - 'Stop doing it!'

Comment: So what he's saying is, "no, no, stop it?" Why is there a も there?

Comment: No the example I gave is a completely different usage. `も` is to express 'as well' or '(you) too'.

Comment: @sawa Kansai should be せいや

Comment: @syockit It can be either. There are several other variations.

Comment: So what does いやいやあなたもたいがい say in English?

Comment: @language hacker 'You are such to a decent degree as well'.