# Understanding 〜てなんだけど

Tags: grammar

> 「あんなのを欲しがるなんて、連邦も物好きよねえ。長いこと使っておい**てなんだけど**、**たいがい得体は知れない**のに」
>
> 「まあ、戦場なら役に立つんじゃない？　こっちも阻電攪乱型はいるみたいだし。〈ジャガーノート〉の方は、あんな歩く棺桶なんか調べてどうするんだよって感じだけど」

86─エイティシックス─Ep.2 ─ラン・スルー・ザ・バトルフロント─〈上〉
安里アサト

They are talking about a communication tool.

How should I understand the usage of the bold part? Namely, the construction 〜てなんだけど? By the way, does the たいがい得体は知れない mean "I don’t know much about how it works", literally?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55361/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26127/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40005/9831

Comment: And these: [Meaning of 大概 in「ボクも大概だ」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/47767/43676), [What does たいがい mean here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1991/43676)

Answer (score 3):

This kind of なんだけど can be understood as a contraction of "A(しておい)て(いう/するのも)なんだけど", roughly meaning "it is awkward/inconsistent/contradictory etc. to say/do after A"

Hopefully the examples explain:

- 食べきっておいていうのもなんだけど、おいしくはない。 It is awkward to say after finishing it, but it was not really delicious.
- 来てもらってなんだけど、あんまり手伝ってもらうことはない I appreciate that you have come, but a bit awkward to say, there is not much to do here.
- 自分で言うのもなんだけど、これは完璧だ It is not right to say this about what I did myself, but this is perfect. (In this case, there is no A of the pattern)

I don't think the translations exactly convey the nuances of the Japanese sentences, but basically なんだけど indicates the situation/action of the speaker is not very consistent with what she says/does.

たいがい means basically "overall" or "most of the time". たいがいX is usually with a word X of negative connotation. For example, たいがいいい加減だ means someone is いい加減 most of the time, if not always. So in this sense たいがい makes the description softer.

So the bold part means ***it may be silly to say this** after having used it for such a long time, **but the tool is rather fishy***.

---

Note that なんだけど itself appears  more "normally".

- 明日のことなんだけど Regarding tomorrow('s schedule)
- 子供が病気なんだけど My kid is ill, so...